# Groupby and keep rows depending on string value

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

I have this DF:

```
In [106]: dfTest = pd.DataFrame( {'name':['a','a','b','b'], 'value':['x','y','x','h']})    
In [107]: dfTest
Out[107]: 
  name value
0    a     x
1    a     y
2    b     x
3    b     h
```

So my intention is to obtain one row per `name` group and the `value` to keep will depend. If for each group of `name` I find `h` in `value`, I'd like to keep it. Otherwise, any `value` would fit, such as:

```
In [109]: dfTest                                                                                         
Out[109]: 
  name value
0    a     x
1    b     h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with `drop_duplicates`:

```
(dfTest.loc[dfTest['value'].eq('h').sort_values().index]
   .drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
)
```

Output:

```
  name value
1    a     y
3    b     h
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
dfTest.reindex(dfTest.groupby('name')['value'].agg(lambda x: (x=='h').idxmax()))
```

Output:

```
      name value
value           
0        a     x
3        b     h
```